# How to add additional information into LSTM to predict future value?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

When using LSTM to predict future value, it's easy to use past value as input and set future value as output.

Taking traffic flow prediction as an example, let's say that our sampling frequency is 20/hour, that is to measure the traffic flow every 3 mins.

We could use past 60 points(3-hour past data) to predict future value, just construct the data set and then fit into LSTM, and things would be done.

However, in this case, traffic flow prediction, besides past value, time is also an important features(i.e. what time it is).

Let's take another example, prediction of passenger flow. In this case, we could use past data to predict future passenger flow. In addition, I believe that features such as whether it's holiday, whether it's weekend, would have impact on future values.

**So, in general:**

**I know some information about the specific future time/day**

**I also want to predict some quantity of that specific future time/day**

**How can I utilize that part of information, i.e., how to use information of future, along with the past data, to predict future quantity?**

Answer (score 1):

Since it not a tagging problem, you would be connecting one dense layer to the output of the LSTM after last recurrence/step. To this last dense layer you can supply the additional features. The intuition is, you get the hidden representation using LSTM for n steps and then concatenate additional features to the hidden representation of the last step and run it through a dense layer(s) finally mapping to a single forecast.

[image]